# Select into multiple tables using table @variables TSQL (or create and fill multiple tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like you to ask if it is possible to select into multiple tables data from one table. 
In the basis table I have a column containing different values and I want to select data into as many tables as distinct values in this column. Below example of how I want this to work:

```
Select A, B, C
Into @newtable
From Table
Where @D=D
```

D can be an index from 1 to N which I can use to make a loop. At each iteration I want to create and fill a new table with unique name (for example name = D value). Is it possible ? Could you help me to write the code ?

Comment: Alarm bells! Why do you have specially named tables? You should have an additional column in one table to partition the data, not multiple specially named tables.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with dynamic sql.

```
declare sql varchar(max),
        @valeWithTableName varchar(max)  

set @valeWithTableName  = '@newtable'
set @sql = 'Select A, B, C Into ' + @valeWithTableName + ' From Table Where @D=D '
```